# Alignment of fluid divs in a container of variable width

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello kind internet beings, I have a question I hope you can assist with. I have a container like so:

[image]

And the inner divs float left so that they are side-by-side in rows. The problem is that when there is an inner div that is taller then the others, the next row is all weird and there is a lot of extra space.

I'd prefer it to look like:

[image]

Each inner div (in the picture it is not to scale) has the same width but might have a different height. Is there some css option to set each row to line up under the tallest item of the previous row, perhaps?

```
           <style>
            .objectContainer
            {   background-color: #e1e8fa; 
                border-radius: 5px; 
                padding:4px; 
                width: 280px; 
                float: left;
                margin: 7px; 
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;  
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;
                box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000000;
                display:inline-block; 
                position:relative;
                vertical-align:top;
            }       

            .innerContainer
            {   padding: 4px; 
                margin: 4px; 
                min-height:  95px;
                max-height:  140px;
                outline: 1px dashed #5c5c5c;
                background-color: white;
            }

            .tab {
                padding-left: 15px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
                -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
                height: 18px;
                width: 150px;
                border-top: 1px dashed;
                border-left: 1px dashed;
                border-right: 1px dashed;
                border-color: #5c5c5c;
                border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
                position: relative;
            }
         </style>



<div id="mainContainer" class="main_container" >
    <div class="main"  style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
        <div  class="listviewheader">

            <div style="clear:both;" class="objectContainer" id="container_2483" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e3c785 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #e3c785 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2483" id="note_2483" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2483" style="clear: both; background-color: #fdfce2; " class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">

                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="objectContainer" id="container_2484" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c1e194 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #c1e194, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #c1e194, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #c1e194 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2484" id="note_2484" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2484" style="clear: both; background-color: #fdfce2; " class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">
                    </br></br></br></br></br></br>
                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="objectContainer" id="container_2496" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e3c785 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #e3c785 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2496" id="note_2496" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2496" style="clear: both;" class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">

                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="objectContainer" id="container_2495" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e3c785 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #e3c785 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2495" id="note_2495" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2495" style="clear: both;" class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">

                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="objectContainer" id="container_2481" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e3c785 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #e3c785, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #e3c785 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2481" id="note_2481" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2481" style="clear: both; background-color: #fdfce2; " class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">

                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="objectContainer" id="container_2482" name="objectContainer">
                <div class="tab" style="float: left; position: relative; left: 3px; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c1e194 , white);  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #c1e194, white); background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #c1e194, white); background: linear-gradient(to right, #c1e194 , white);">x</div>
                <input type="hidden" name="note_2482" id="note_2482" value="">
                <div style="float: right; position: relative; "></div>
                    <div id="innerContainer_2482" style="clear: both; background-color: #fdfce2; " class="innerContainer" name="innerContainer">

                </div><div style='clear:both;'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style='clear:both;'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can't you just use **actual** rows?

Comment: You might want to look at [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co).

Comment: @Terry Not sure this is the usual Masonry type question. Simple *actual* rows should be sufficient.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion how I can make this with actual rows? The page is generated using PHP and the number of divs changes. The page size is also dependent on the client. PHP can't know the width of the page to make rows since it is server side.

Comment: pls see my jsfiddle. it is working. i added wrappers around each three containers and then added display:inline-block vertical align:top to the wrappers

Answer (score 3):

set the css for your inner divs to `display:inline-block;` `position:relative` and most importantly, `vertical-align:top;`

that should do it!

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have made the change and included sample code above. Unfortunately the issue still happens.

Comment: That is all well and great, and I understand that I can do that. The problem is that there won't always be three divs in a row. There could be two, four, five. It is variable based on the size of the window. Therefore being this is generated using PHP and the server wont know how many objects are in a row, I can not simply add a wrapper to each row.

Comment: here, i just cleaned up your code and took out the inline style and put it in css. http://jsfiddle.net/e9ysj1u6/2/

Comment: and i removed the wrappers

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap to separate divs by their rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box1">box 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box2">box 2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box3">box 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box4">box 4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box5">box 5</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="box6">box 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks something like this with the height and background color changed.
[image: bg_img]

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid system. Either bootstrap or zurb foundation will work fine. If you decide to do it on your own I can tell you the most important trick is to use the "after" pseudo selector to clear the float. The following gives you the basic grid design. The box sizing is only necessary to avoid trouble with optional paddings in the columns.

```css
Then CSS with

    .row:after{
        content: "";
        clear: both;
        display: block;
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .col-33{
        width: 33.33%;
        float: left;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-33">
            First col
        </div>
        <div class="col-33">
            Second col
        </div>
        <div class="col-33">
            Third col
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-33">
            First col
        </div>
        <div class="col-33">
            Second col
        </div>
        <div class="col-33">
            Third col
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would give a static three columns I believe. The number of divs that fit side-by-side depends on the container size, which is based on the clients window size.

Comment: One more argument to use bootstrap or foundation. These use media queries to retrieve the screen width and reduce the number of divs in a customizable manner. Again, you can dive deeper into the topic and do it on your own. You will learn a lot ;)

Comment: @RaymondNijland You erased the second row in your fiddle and put all columns into one. That's why it didn't work. My code describes the basic technique of a (non responsive) three column grid system and works fine. See https://jsfiddle.net/qk6ww5bL/1/

Comment: @klawipo oeps indeed mine mistake

Comment: I am not using rows with a set number of divs in each row as the width of the container is variable.

Comment: See the other of Felix. The cols will appear underneath each other when the browser width is smaller then a given amount of xy pixels (xy has a default value i don't know, but it is adjustable).